# Out of memory in perl after adding entry in ENV dictionary

Tags: perl

I am getting Out of memory in perl at this line:

> $ENV{"CONF"} = $config;

I did a debug and here is the back trace:

```
> Out of memory! $ = DB::fake::at_exit() called from file 
> `/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/perl5db.pl' line 8743 $ = DB::END() called from
> file `script.pl' line 0
> DB<2> t $ENV{"CONF"} = $config; main::((eval
> 15)[/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/perl5db.pl:620]:3): 3:      $ENV{"CONF"} =
> $config; Out of memory! Callback called exit. END failed--call queue
> aborted.
> Config::DESTROY(/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/sun4-solaris-thread-multi/Config.pm:1269):
> 1269:   sub DESTROY { }
> IO::Handle::DESTROY(/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/sun4-solaris-thread-multi/IO/Handle.pm:326):
> 326:    sub DESTROY {}
> IO::Handle::DESTROY(/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5/sun4-solaris-thread-multi/IO/Handle.pm:326):
> 326:    sub DESTROY {}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: in confing there is a string "CONF_5618_01"

Comment: Try make [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The most probably it is not this line what causes it. Is it last line of a block or last line of the script or last line before `exec` or `exit`? It's because I see `DB::fake::at_exit()` and several `DESTROY` handlers. It is usually when some variables going out of scope and GC kicks in. Welcome to the magic word of Perl sideefects and surprises.

Comment: BTW, Are You sure it is a string in `$config`. What is the output of `say ref $config`?

Comment: I get syntax error at "say ref $config". It always in the same place the "Out of memory" error, when I put in ENV{CONFIG} something. Sometime it pass without "Out of memory" and sometimes not.